# mysql: job failded to start. mysqld.sock is missing

Tags: mysql

How can I fix this and start mysql-server?

After /etc/init.d/mysql start or service mysql start I get the message start: "Job failed to start"
And after # mysqld I get this:

```
mysqld
121123 11:33:33 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
121123 11:33:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Unknown error 1146
121123 11:33:33 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
121123 11:33:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123 11:33:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
121123 11:33:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
121123 11:33:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121123 11:33:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123 11:33:33 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123 11:33:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123 11:33:34 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123 11:33:34 [ERROR] Aborting
121123 11:33:34  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
121123 11:33:35  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
121123 11:33:35 [Note]
```

I try to do what mysql say me to do:

```
mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

And yes, /var/run/mysql is empty:

```
mysql_upgrade
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Running 'mysqlcheck' with connection arguments: '--port=3306' '--socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' 
mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

And this is my file /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf |grep sock
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Then I try to reinstall mysql from cero:

```
  apt-get purge mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server
  rm -R /var/lib/mysql
  rm -R /etc/mysql
  rm -R /var/run/mysqld
  userdel mysql
  apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Then, after typing my root password for mysql I get this error:

```
 | Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                              │  
 │                                                                               │  
 │ An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative     │  
 │ user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or   │  
 │ because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.                     │  
 │                                                                               │  
 │ You should check the account's password after the package installation.       │  
 │                                                                               │  
 │ Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more   │  
 │ information.
```

And again I can't start mysql getting the same messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're running into a circular dependency of MySQL not being able to start and running the Debian configuration scripts in an attempt to fix that requires MySQL to be running.

Try to re-initialize your data directory 'offline' using [`mysql_install_db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html).

Comment: I GOT IT.
I tried `mysql_install_db --basedir /etc/mysql` and I get `Could not find errmsg.sys`
Then I decide to copy from other linux machine this file (and some others that where missed):
`scp /usr/share/mysql/english/* root@machine:/usr/share/mysql/english`
`scp /usr/share/mysql/*.sql root@machine:/usr/share/mysql/`
And when I run once more:
´mysql_install_db --basedir /etc/mysql´ I got:
`Filling help tables... OK`
Then I run:
`mysql_safe`
And it worked (everything as root, ofc)

Comment: @Freefri If those files were actually missing, then I guess something is wrong with the packages or something prevented proper installation of the [`mysql-server-core-5.1`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/mysql-server-core-5.1) package. Those were regular Debian packages from the main repository?

Comment: I've intall `mysql-server` that I think it installs `mysql-server-core-5.5` from Ubuntu's 12.10 repository. Somthing went wrong in the installation and it didn't finish properly. The installation returned an error

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not have 3 socket files in your my.cnf

try the following:

`dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server`

You will be asked(promped) to set a password for the root user. Good luck

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` won't help as that requires MySQL to be running. See the error in the question.

Comment: with `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server` I get mysql-server broken package. Remember that my installation failed (`An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative`)